# How to dynamically merge videos in react native

Tags: android, ios, video, react-native, ffmpeg

Hey I’m trying to make a kitten app but I got a very difficult challenge which is to merge videos dynamically:
The logic is the following:

1 - User1 creates a video, this can be uploading an existing one, or recording a new one.

2 - Video will be save in DB (firebase in this case) and showed on feed like in youtube.

3 - User2 clicks on user1 video button “join kitten”

4 - User2  is now on camera screen to record a video to merge with user1’s video.

5 - user2 video will recorded to the length of user1’s video

6 - the merge will keep audio of user1’s video

7 - result video gets watermark

8 - merged video will be saved in DB(or locally) and displayed in another feed.

I’m very new to each native and I don’t code frequently. 
I found [this code](https://github.com/MostWantIT/react-native-video-editor) on GitHub, but I’m having issues to use the module but gives me error when trying to install it.
The closest example that I found was [this app](https://www.smule.com/)

With ffmpeg would more or less do a part of it or maybe it all, but I'm not familiar with it and I would know how to implement this in react native

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp1 2> /dev/null & \
```

ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp2 2> /dev/null & \

ffmpeg -f mpegts -i "concat:temp1|temp2" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4

Comment: I also want this functionality in my app, have you find any solution?